# Replace rows having at least one duplicate number or one zero by a user defined row

Tags: matlab, replace, rows

I have a matrix having rows with repeated numbers.

```
A= [ 2 3 6;
     4 7 4;
     8 7 2;
     1 3 1;
     7 8 2 ]
```

The codes below find those rows and replace them with a Dummy_row `[1 2 3]`

```
new_A=[ 2 3 6;
        1 2 3;
        8 7 2;
        1 2 3;
        7 8 2 ]
```

This are the codes:

### CODE NUMBER 1   (@Bruno)

```
Dummy_row = [1 2 3];

b = any(~diff(sort(A,2),1,2),2);
 A(b,:) = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(b),1)
```

### CODE NUMBER 2 (@Kamtal)

```
Dummy_row = [1 2 3];
b = diff(sort(A,2),1,2);
b = sum(b == 0,2);
b = b > 0;
c = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(b),1);
b = b' .* (1:length(b));
b = b(b > 0);
newA = A; 
newA(b,:) = c
```

Note: both codes Number 1 and 2 perform the task efficiently.

### Question

How can this code(either code num 1 or num 2) be modified such that it also replaces any rows having at least one zero with the Dummy_row?

Comment: What language is that?

Answer (score 1):

### Code 1

```
b = any(~diff(sort(A,2),1,2),2) | any(A==0,2); % <-- Only change
A(b,:) = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(b),1);
```

### Code 2

```
b = diff(sort(A,2),1,2);
b = sum(b == 0,2);
b = (b > 0) | any(A==0,2); % <-- Only change
c = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(b),1);
b = b' .* (1:length(b));
b = b(b > 0);
newA = A; 
newA(b,:) = c;
```

By the way: **Code1** basically does the same thing that **Code2** does, just that it uses [logical-indexing](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) instead of doing the unnecessary conversion from logical indexes to index positions.